# Relation between the image space of the controllability matrix and the PHB test

Tags: control-theory

I am trying to understand the relation between the controllability matrix and the PHB test. More precisely, I want to know the relation between the image space of the controllability matrix (also known as the reachable space) and the image space of the PHB matrix.

Let $C = [B, AB , A^2B , \ldots , A^{n-1}B]$ be the controllability matrix and $[A-\lambda I , B]$ be the PHB matrix. We know that the system is controllable iff $\operatorname{rank}(C) = n$ or $\operatorname{rank}[A-\lambda_i I , B] = n$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$).

Question is: Is it true that $\operatorname{Im}(C) = \operatorname{Im}([A-\lambda_1 I , B]) \cap \operatorname{Im}([A-\lambda_2 I , B]) \cap \ldots \cap \operatorname{Im}([A-\lambda_n I , B])$?

Edit: I've just seen a (deleted) answer to my question and I want to use this opportunity to clarify my question. It is clear to me that my statement holds if the system is controllable (since it implies that $\operatorname{rank}(C) = \operatorname{rank}[A-\lambda_i I, B] = n$, $\forall i$). My question is more general in the sense that I also want to consider the case where $\operatorname{rank}(C)<n$. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed that was why the answer was deleted as I had misread the question.

Comment: I thought so. I took this opportunity to clarify my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the claim to be false. Please check this counter-example. Consider the linear control system with,

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Notice that $B \in \mathrm{null}(A)$ so the system cannot be controllable.
Check that the controllability matrix is,

$$
[B, AB,A^2B] = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

so it follows that,

$$
\mathrm{im}(C) = \mathrm{span}\left\{B\right\}
$$

Now let us compute the PBH matrices. The eigenvalues are $1$ (repeated twice) and $0.$ So,

$$
\begin{aligned}{}
[A - 1 I, B] &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \end{array}\right)\\
[A - 0 I, B] &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & -1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) 
\end{aligned}
$$

Clearly $\mathrm{im}([A - 0 I, B]) = \mathbb{R}^3$ so it suffices to compute the image of the former matrix. Observe,

$$
\mathrm{im}([A - 1 I, B]) = \mathrm{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$

It follows that the intersection of images of the PBH matrices do not agree with the image of the controllability matrix.

Comment: Although, maybe a weaker statement, that the image of $C$ is contained in this intersection, may be true.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example, Rollen.